# Tornado ImportError: No module

Tags: python-2.7

**UPDATE**
So I got rid of `import tornado io.loop` and it turns out that the next error concerned a failure to import tornado.web, which can only mean that tornado isn't installed properly **OR** the server isn't able to find tornado. I don't understand why this is happening even though I have installed tornado with:

```
sudo pip install tornado
```

Comment: which Ubuntu are you using? There is no 14.0, only 14.04 or 14.10... Further, did you try to `import tornado` on a interactive python shell?

Comment: How do you access it?

Comment: Through a console, PuTTY and WinsCP

Comment: When connected via putty, just enter `python` without any further argument. Then, a prompt appears like `>>> `. There, type `import tornado.ioloop`. What happens?

Comment: Try 'python --version' to make sure you're really using Python 2.7.

Comment: @skyline75489 yep it's showing I'm using Python 2.7.5

Comment: @StackOverQuestions Then I suggest you to try `import tornado` in a interactive python shell.

Comment: Can you explain how you got rid of the first error, and can you show the traceback for the second error. Further, can you show the relevant lines of the 'app.py' script (i.e., the first 15-20 lines or so)?

Comment: Hey guys I found the solution, I didn't move the tornado folder into the exact same folder as my project which is why my app was detecting anything.

Comment: You've now updated your question by completely wiping your old question, which makes a lot of comments less or irrelevant. Also, your mentioned solution doesn't make sense: tornado should be installed in your `site-packages` folder and be picked up by Python; it should *not* live in your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i got similar error when i had different python versions on my server (python27 and pypi), so you might ensure that you have installed tornado package to python27 interpreter by this command `sudo python -m pip install tornado`

Answer (score 0):

I had so much trouble getting tornado 5.0 installed on Ubuntu 14.05 with python 2.7.6. So I just installed the older version of tornado using pip install tornado==4.5.2